# Showing two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to show that each of the following matrices

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\quad , 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-i&0\\
i&0&-i\\
0&i&0
\end{pmatrix}
 , 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

are equivalent to one of the following

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

It is a relatively simple but time consuming problem to construct a similarity transformation. I have nine real independent variables and 9 equations to check for each matrix. I want to know if there is any process or software that could help me do this calculation?

Comment: Which kind of "equivalent" are you using?

Comment: @Henning Sorry. I am following a physics book and these matrices are actually representations. Two representations were defined to be equivalent if their matrices are related by a similarity transformation. This was what I had in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned a "similarity transform", I presume your "equivalent" means "similar"; also I presume this is over $\mathbb C$.  Well, the first thing I would do is find the eigenvalues of each matrix; the second (if necessary) is the Jordan canonical form.  As for software, Maple will handle this quite easily; I imagine
most other CAS's will also.

EDIT: Oops, all of your first three matrices are similar to each other, and none is similar to any of the last three.  Are you sure you quoted the question right?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The first three matrices are what physicists call spin 1 representation. The final three matrices are the adjoint representation of SU(2) (excluding a phase factor of -i). The question is to show that the two representations are equivalent (a result which is used later to construct roots). I phrased only the computational part in my question.

Comment: @kuchnahi The top matrices are Hermitian hence their eigenvalues are real. Bottom left two are skew-symmetric and hence have eigenvalues pure imaginary. This means they can't be similar. The only option is the bottom right but that also has complex eigenvalues.

Comment: The bottom right doesn't work already because it is invertible and none of the other 5 are.

Comment: Sorry,you all were right. I made a type in the third matrix

Comment: That "phase factor" of $-i$ makes a big difference.  After multiplying by that, they are all similar.  What you want, though, is a single unitary transformation that transforms all three matrices on the top to $-i$ times matrices on the bottom.

Comment: In fact, if the top 3 matrices are $A_j$, consider $U A_j U^{-1}$ where $U = \pmatrix{-1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2}\cr
-i/\sqrt{2} & 0 & -i/\sqrt{2}\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$

Answer (score -1):

Two matrices are similar if their traces are equal.

Comment: So every traceless matrix is the zero matrix?

Comment: This is true only for $1\times 1$ matrices.